# UICollectionView edge to edge layout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Goal: edge-to-edge UICollectionView with 2 cells on all size iPhones.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

   let screenSize = collectionView.bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width
    print("Zhenya: \(screenWidth)") // prints correct 375, which is half of iPhone 6
    let cellEdgeLength: CGFloat = screenWidth / 2.0

    return CGSize(width: cellEdgeLength, height: cellEdgeLength)
}
```

Also

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self

    let flow = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    flow.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.vertical
    flow.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    flow.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = flow
}
```

However on iPhone 6:

[image]

Collection Cell attributes:

[image]

Collection View attributes:

[image]

**Update:** 
func for gradient, that actually gets the right width: 
(located at custom UICollectionViewCell class)

```
  func addGradient () {

    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = gradientView.bounds
    let topColor = UIColor(red:0.07, green:0.07, blue:0.07, alpha:1)
    let botomColor = UIColor.clear
    gradient.colors = [topColor.cgColor, botomColor.cgColor]

    if gradientWasRemoved == false {
    gradientView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    } else if gradientWasRemoved == true {
        self.addSubview(gradientView)
    }
```

**Update 2:**
Note: Testing on iPhone 7 Plus. 
I found that UICollectionViewFlowLayout overrides cell size crated in `sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` (seems like it)
With this code:

```
    let flow = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let screenSize = collectionView.bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width
    let cellEdgeLength: CGFloat = screenWidth / 2.0

    flow.itemSize =  CGSize(width: cellEdgeLength, height: cellEdgeLength)

    flow.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.vertical
    flow.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    flow.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = flow
```

I have this:

[image]

Then I decided manual specify cell edge length (half of iPhone7Plust width = 207):

```
 let cellSide: CGFloat = 207
 flow.itemSize =  CGSize(width: cellSide, height: cellSide)

 flow.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.vertical
 flow.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
 flow.minimumLineSpacing = 0
 collectionView.collectionViewLayout = flow
```

I get this:

[image]

Comment: have your tried `return CGSize(width: (self.collectionView!.frame.width/2), height: (self.collectionView!.frame.width/2))`  instead? frame = a view's location and size using the parent view's coordinate system
bounds = a view's location and size using its own coordinate system

Comment: Didn't work. 
What can give some clues - i have a gradient view in my cell, and it takes the right width. I will update my og post with code for the gradient. Maybe it will help.

Comment: maybe. I can see you have constraints to that gradient view

Comment: what are the constraints for? Have you tried without?

Comment: so, for the cell, there are no constraints, only "descendant". 
for the collection view, i don't think those numbers affect anything. I delete them and nothing changes.

Comment: can you try this return CGSize(width: (self.collectionView!.frame.width/2)-40, height: 120). because we need padding space between row 1 and row 2 .

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. 
Problem was in the inner imageView autolayout settings. I didn't specify them. 
Why that little piece of BS was getting on the way of my flow.itemSize, I don't know. 
What is more weird to me, is why when manually specified cellEdgeLength as 207 in the second update, all of the sudden, it did override the lack of imageView constraints.